# Want to store 3:00 AM in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I know its a childish question but I m not able to fix it . plz help me out of this.

I want to store

```
3:00 AM
```

in my database.

I m taking TIME type in database . Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: And what exactly happens/doesn't work?

Comment: @user1790439: phpMyAdmin is not a database. But it means you use MySQL.

Comment: Did you bother to read [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)?

Answer (score 3):

That time is `03:00` as computers use the (much better) 24-hour format. You can store it easily in any database column that has a type like `TIME`.

Example

```
INSERT INTO whatever (ts) VALUES ('03:00');
```